# Javascript : Detect existing browsers on customers machine

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way from JS , we can detect how many and which browsers are installed on user's machine.Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You can detect the running browser though but not installed one.

Comment: The close reason seems odd, given this is clearly a programming question. Was it edited?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I agree.  I don't understand why this was closed.  The answer is "no", but it seems like a legit programming question.

Comment: @jfriend00: Reopened now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to examine what software is installed on a given user's machine via a browser page using standard web-safe techniques.

To do so would require the ability to look outside the browser's sandbox and this opens up all sorts of security vulnerabilities which is why it is not allowed in the browser.

---

The usual work-around is to request that the user download an executable program that is built for their platform (Mac, Windows, etc...), run it and have it report back to you.  But, this is an onerous step that many users will not do or will fail to do and many systems will attempt to warn/block because of the potential security isssues.  It cannot be done automatically without significant user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

you can't, unless you inject in a program to run in the user's machine, and do a system search and send back the data, which is the very definition of virus and trojan.